# What does "please cost both" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Q1. DDR3 can be configured as 2x8-bit or 1x16-bit.
>   1x16 bit is preferred but if 2x8-bit is the cheaper option, please cost both.

I understood the former sentence but I want to know whether '*please cost both*' means you should *buy* both Or you just *consider* both, not buying.

Comment: I have removed your second sentence on a suggested edit as it is not explained and no specific issue is raised with it. Take the [tour] and see [ask] for more.

Comment: *Cost* means "give me the price of" here, but personally I think it sounds ugly and jargonish.  [It's definition #10 here.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cost)

Answer (score 3):

"Please cost both" means please provide prices for both options.

***[To cost](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cost)***:

> - to calculate the future cost of something:
>     *My boss asked me to cost the materials for the new fence and gate.
>     Has your plan been properly costed (out)?*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

"Please cost both" is an inelegant way of asking for prices of both the products. A better way to ask is "Please (give me), prices for both". The reason is that cost and price are not synonyms and have distinctly different meanings.

The verb 'to cost (something)', as an intransitive verb (as used in the example), means to calculate, to assess, or to estimate the total cost of a product (for example, to determine the selling price of a manufactured product or the landed cost of a purchased product). Example: 'In view of increased raw material costs, he costed the product xyz again'. (Note: 'costed', here, is right).

The verb 'to cost (someone)', as a transitive verb, means the amount of money that someone needed to incur or pay. Example: 'The foreign trip had cost him a packet' (Note: 'costed', here, is wrong).

The verb 'to price' means arrive at an amount as price (to sell / transfer). Example: 'The increased costing has forced us to price the product higher'.